# Append current date to log file name log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the below log4j.properties file

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/C:/Debug.log

log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now i have a requirement to have file name as Debug.log.2015-11-26 (append system date).
When the server is restarted it should automatically create the file name appending with system date.

I have tried below change

```
   # Define the root logger with appender file
    log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

    # Define the file appender
    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=/C:/Debug.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}

    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This doesnt append the current date. I have also went through DailyFileAppender, but the purpose of dailyfile appender will be create a new log file every day which i dont want. As for my requirement, new log should get created only on server restart.

Can someone point me out what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: [This](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) might help.

Comment: I have already went through DailyFileRollingAppender, but this doesnt solve my purpose as it creates log file everyday and current date log file doesnt have system date. It rolls the logs file every night and append the date. My requirement is different. Please go through the question again.

Comment: Set the log file programatically using org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile().